# Float two DIVs by width in px and percentage

Tags: html, css, css-float

How to `float` two `DIV`s side by side as the width of one is defined in pixel and the other should fill the available width in the parent `DIV`? The point is that the content of second `DIV` may be blank; thus, I cannot leave its width empty.

```
.div1 {
float:left;
display:block;
width:200px
}

.div2 {
float:left;
display:block;
width: [... 100% - 200px ...]
}
```

Comment: check: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-22-fluid-fixed/

Answer (score 6):

Simple - float the first div and give only margin equal to first div width to second div (a div is a block element so it already has a 100% width - just for the sake of validation you can add `width:auto`):

```
.div1 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: violet;
}

.div2 {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 200px;    
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;    
}
```

There's a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gFyY3/

Comment: I have this problem and know the solution, but am absolutely bothered by the fact of having to declare the same thing (200px) in two different places. The "right" thing would be to make changes in only one place. Would there be a way to to it, with the same net result, with CSS only?

Comment: @heltonbiker - No. That's how it is. CSS is not a programming language. If you want to define variables use SASS or LESS.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have heard about them, but I think I am more prone to use (the-all-the-way programmatic option) javascript, then.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to use float, you can also use the inline-block display-type. Saves you from clearing the floats etc.

```
<div style="width: 250px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
Some content <br> More <br> More
</div>

<div style="display: inline-block;">
Some more content  <br> More <br> More   <br> More <br> More   <br> More <br> More 
</div>
```

There's a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Neograph734/tbqpy/

Answer (score 0):

You could set div1 to position absolute, that it lays over div2, then you give div2 a width of 100% and all child-elements of div2 a margin left of 200px.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure your second div will always be blank, I suggest you to use the [Clear property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp) like this example:

```
div{
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
div.clear{
  clear: both;
}
```

Then you won't need a second div.

But if you want to fill the second with content I'd rather suggest you to set both div with a percentage value like:

```
div.first{
  float: left;
  max-width: 20%;
}
div.second{
  float: left;
  max-width: 80%;
}
```

Hope this help.

Aymeric.